# Conditionally chaining where clauses in Rails ActiveRecord queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a form that when filled has to trigger a particular query, depending on which parameters the form has, so I have a method in my model that I believe should look like this:

```
def form_query(params)

  query = ''
  if params.has_key?('size')
    query = query.where(size: params['size'])
  end

  if params.has_key?('title')
    query = query.where(title: params['title'])
  end

  # More conditionals depending on params.
end
```

My question is, what does `query` have to be at the beginning? I put `query = ''`, but I am wondering what has to be the base case, so I can conditionally add more 'where' clauses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Queries aren't strings; they're query objects. So you want something like

```
query = YourModel.scoped # Rails 3; in Rails 4, use .all
if params.has_key?('size')
  query = query.where(size: params['size'])
end
```

etc.

Comment: If you are using rails 3 (or 2 for that matter), make sure to use `YourModel.scoped` rather than `YourModel.all`. In rails 3, the latter will immediately return all rows in your table.

Comment: Good catch, fixed. I've never actually used .all to do this; there has always been some constant part of the query to use as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can update your code as below:

```
  def self.form_query(params)
    options = {}
    fields = ["body", "title"].freeze  ## Add other options
    if params.present?
      fields.each do |field|
        options[field] = params[field] if params[field]
      end
    end
    if options.present?
      where(options) 
    else
       all  ## or nil if you don't want to show any records in view
    end
  end
```

Also, `form_query` should be a class method in your model.
Add more options in the `fields` array that you would like to query against. 
It not only makes your code compact but also makes a single database call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more condensed version of Kirti Thorat's version:

```
FIELDS = ["size", "title"].freeze  ## Add other options

def self.form_query(params)
  return all unless params.present?

  options = params.select { |k, _v| FIELDS.include? k.to_s }
  options.present? ? where(options) : all
end
```

I have done `k.to_s` so you can pass params keys as either strings or symbols.

If you want to return `nil` if no params are passed you can do this:

```
FIELDS = ["size", "title"].freeze  ## Add other options

def self.form_query(params)
  return unless params.present?

  options = params.select { |k, _v| FIELDS.include? k.to_s }
  where(options) if options.present? 
end
```